# javascript color function with mysql table values error

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql-server

I have a website about Christmas lights. I am using python flask for the sql database and query. 
My sql tables columns look like this for user 1 (this is just an example)

```
column name: id text   blue   green  yellow   red   orange   pink

value:        1  text    on     NULL    on      on    NUll    NULL
```

I need to get just the color data using flask which would probably be a sql statement.

More importantly, I need a JavaScript function to check the column values and if they have on in the color, print a statement. 
So far, I have

```
function colorCh(el){
    var list;
        for (var color in list){
            if (list[color] == 'on')
                print("Good")
        }
    }
```